# How to add an "extra stack" in Bar graph using dimple.js?

Tags: javascript, dimple.js

I have a drawn a bar graph using dimple.js

http://jsfiddle.net/keshav_1007/Lkvm27o4/1/  - here is the fiddle

```
var yMax = 520; // overriding y axis
var popup;
var score=8000/100;
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 300, 400);
var data = [{
    "Brand":"A", 
    "Day":"Mon", 
    "SalesVolume":10 },
    { 
    "Brand":"B", 
    "Day":"Mon", 
    "SalesVolume":20 },
    { 
    "Brand":"C", 
    "Day":"Mon", 
    "SalesVolume":20 },
    { 
    "Brand":"D", 
    "Day":"Mon", 
    "SalesVolume":20 },
    { 
    "Brand":"E", 
    "Day":"Mon",
    "SalesVolume":20 },
    {  
    "Brand":"F", 
    "Day":"Mon", 
    "SalesVolume":50 }];
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);

myChart.setBounds(100, 10, 250, 250)
var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Day");
var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "SalesVolume");
y.overrideMax = yMax;
var s = myChart.addSeries("Brand", dimple.plot.bar);
s.barGap=0.8;
var lgnd = myChart.addLegend(80, 300, 300, 30, "left");

myChart.draw();
```

In this bar graph i need to place the last stack that is `[{"Brand":"F","Day":"Mon","SalesVolume":50 }]` always on the top of the bar without changing the default order of the other stacks.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an order rule to the series like this:

```
s.addOrderRule(function (a, b) {
    var result = 0;
    if (a["Brand"] === "F" && b["Brand"] !== "F") {
        result = 1;
    } else if (a["Brand"] !== "F" && b["Brand"] === "F") {
        result = -1;
    }
    return result;
});
```

This will place anything where the brand is "F" last and evaluate to 0 for other elements meaning the default ordering will be applied in these cases.

This can be made dynamic by using a function to return the comparer:

```
function getComparer (dimension, lastValue) {
    return function (a, b) {
        var result = 0;
        if (a[dimension] === lastValue && b[dimension] !== lastValue) {
            result = 1;
        } else if (a[dimension] !== lastValue && b[dimension] === lastValue) {
            result = -1;
        }
        return result;
    };
}
```

Then you can call it:

```
s.addOrderRule(getComparer("Brand", "F"));
```

Comment: can we make this function dynamic?? because in my case "F" will not be  "F" all the time it may differ for each in my 21 screens.

Comment: Thanks John it works perfectly... can we set a specific color for this bar(this stack) alone.. as i am plotting the graph it is taking the default set of values. i need to set a specific color for this graph alone.. let me know how we can do that?

Comment: i tried using d3 but i couldnt give a specific color for that specific stack in the bar graph.. :(

Comment: how to give a specific color to the stack which is made to come on top of all the stacks in the bar graph.. i tried many ways but i couldnt get it.. please let me know..